# How do I audit cgroup changes

Tags: audit, auditd, cgroup

I have a container process that is mysteriously changing cgroups long after it has been started. How do I track down who/what is changing it? I tried watching my audit log when manually doing a cgclassify command to switch my process and nothing got logged.

Comment: Do you have any output you could share to illustrate your issue/situation? A good start might be the output/data that allowed you to see the cgroup change in the first place.

Comment: I don't know what you could mean by output?  I mean, I have cAdvisor setup and running and a Prometheus collecting that data and a Grafana visualizing it.  But really, when the application is started, a systemctl status of its PID shows one CGroup.  Later on, it shows another.  The reason I noticed this in the first place is because the graph of CPU usage dropped to 0 even though the application was still running.